# Where are classes in a module's `$classes` variable set?

Tags: 7, theming

I am new to Drupal. I am styling a theme, but have noticed there are some classes affecting a module's layout.

When I examine the module's .tpl.php file I find:

```
<div class="<?php print $classes ?>">
```

Which is where the classes I want to alter are appearing.

I tried looking for where this is set by editing the page, clicking on the little gear icon for that module and having a look at the CSS properties option, but this was empty.

I then looked at the module's settings themselves, but there are no options there to set styles.

Would anyone know where this `$classes` variable is set?

Comment: They are set in the _preprocess() function for the theme hook.

Comment: @Jaypan thanks! Sorry to bother you, but would you know where I might find that?

Comment: Probably in the .module file @MeltingDog, but if there are `include` or `require`s at the top, or another file specified in `hook_theme`, it might be different

Comment: What is the template file name?

Comment: @Jaypan it's a .tpl for a custom module someone in my company made.

Comment: Then it will probably be in a theme function in the module. Go find the hook_theme function and look for the name of the template. It will tell you what the 'theme key' (key in the array). Search in the module where that theme key is used.

Comment: Try doing a search for `['classes_array'][] =` and that might give you some insight where the classes are being set.

Comment: @MeltingDog The file name is what is important, in order to determine the name of the preprocess fuction. What is the file name?